# How to add jars from a local directory in Java

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jar, war

I have a java project. I'm looking to make it read the jars from the disk it's running on-- from the directory I defined on the `.properties` file. So by this, I no longer will include those jars in the WEB-INF directory (its a web application) but read it from my local disk when i'm running it. When I .war it up, it won't include those jars in the pack, but reserve a link to those resources. when deployed on the server, it'll this time get those jars into its path from the disk location on the server by using that link/reference.

How to do this?

I'm developing on Eclipse Neon. I'm not using maven or any other build tool.

//---------------------

EDIT:

Eg. I'm looking to make the application read the database jars from the database's installation directory on the server.

Comment: You want to load classes at runtime from this jar or is it only for "data" ?

Comment: @PeterMmm classes. pls read edit

Comment: You are talking about to load the JDBC driver at runtime and the JDBC jar is not on the JVM classpath ? This may help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime

Comment: @PeterMmm  looks to be it.